# Editing hidden files in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, windows-7, hidden-files

I currently have hidden files displaying in netbeans 7.3.1.  I can even open the files and make changes but when I try to save I get an (Access is Denied) message.

Just to check I tried opening the same file in notepad, attempted the same thing and the save was successful.

I assume it has to do with a permission issue between netbeans and the file on my windows system.

I'm running Windows 7 x64 SP1

I cannot just run netbeans as administrator.

I can't seem to find anything online about this, every link that comes up has to do with simply displaying hidden files in netbeans which I have done already.

Answer (score 0):

The files I downloaded began with a `.` (.header.html, etc) which I know usually means hidden.  In order to proceed my work I manually removed the dot assuming it would allow me to edit the files.  It did not, so I went ahead and checked the file properties and apparently it was still considered hidden.  I then unchecked hidden and saved and was able to edit the files in netbeans perfectly fine.  I wanted to see if I can keep the `.` and have the hidden field unchecked and it works perfectly fine.

I know the `.` signifying hidden is more or less linux specific, but in every version of windows I've used it seemed like the `.` had the same effect.  What happened was I copied these files from an older computer (windows xp) so the file must have retained the flag but in windows 7 the `.` has no influence.  I just checked to confirm by creating a file `.test.html` and the hidden flag was not triggered.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the hidden file privilege from the files that you want to edit. In the menu bar click organize from there select folder and layout options. Now You will see a lot of options click the ones that say to display hidden files.